# Design approaches for storing emails in an application

Tags: file, design-patterns, database-design, postgresql, storage

I want to discuss design approaches for an application we need to implement. The application  needs to store and later process emails. We have about 2000 emails a day, the average size including attachements is about 2MB and we need to store them for 3 month.

Approach 1:

Store the email on the filesystem and insert only the path in the database.

Approach 2:

Store the complete email in a CLOB field in the database.

Where are the advantages and disadvantages of both design approaches?

Comment: How often do you need to refer to the contents of the email over that three month period?  That will be a major influence on the decision to store the contents in the database or not.

Comment: The emails are only processed once, after that they are only "achived" for the case we need to analyse something.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing it in the database, CLOBs are slow but not too much slower than getting it off the file system.  Your disaster recovery story becomes much easier if everything is in one place.

I'd also use a pointer to CLOBs in another table if you're querying the table in question more often than to access the email contents.

Comment: With the term disaster recovery you bring me to another point. As we do not have too much load on our db, I'm thinking about using the new feature of synchronous replication of postgres 9.1.  Then a transaction is only committed when it is stored in both databases.  When storing CLOBs up to 2MB in the db do you think synchronous replication is something I can use?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the synchronous replication, but if you don't have tremendous throughput I would think it could be easily managed with ~2mb or so transactions.  Will you be doing any bulk-loading type operations to this table?

Comment: No, we do not have bulk-loading.

Comment: With postgresql I'd use either a text type or a bytea type.  Both can handle field sizes of about 1G so they're plenty big enough.  text type enforces encoding etc, while bytea is a binary storage method. They also support automatic out of line storage and compression.